# Oracle COPY command writes NULL to column value in some occasional cases, instead of real values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, copy, sqlplus

Faced twice during this week with the cases when Oracle COPY command writes NULL to column value  meanwhile source value is not NULL.
I am using this command to copy data between 2 databases.
In the source database column A have all values <> NULL;
COPY command works without any error but in the target table 40% rows contain NULL in column A... 
As additional info - ALL! values in this column have exactly the same lenght (varchar2(12))
Why command works that way?  Does anyone has faced such issue?

Thank you in the advance!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What result will be for the following select statement? `select count(*) from source_table where a is null`.

Comment: comparison with NULL was being done correctly - IS NULL . Sorry that wrote it in such not obvious way. Rownum in both tables are identical. And for the remaining 60% were copied correct values.

Comment: Wanted to add more details: 1. I ran COPY command from SQL Developer 17.2.0., not from SQL+; 2. Source and target table have identical structure - columns order, datatype; 3. The most important - 60% of  rows were copied correcly.